# Create a facebook login session with passportjs using existing access key?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

tl;dr: Is there any way to create a facebook login session with passportjs using existing access key?

I'm working on a product that is composed from a website , a mobile app and a nodejs server that serves both entities. registration is possible using facebook login from both mobile app and the website. Passportjs perfectly handles the facebook login procedure from the website, while keeping the users details in a mongodb server.

Login from the android app is implemented with the facebookSDK. Once the user is logged in , I file a request to our internal server with the access key and the facebook id in order to submit a request to facebook and authorize the user + request her details.
Right now, I'm using 2 different libraries to do that (passport for registration from the website and node-facebook to request the users details from an existing token) but that's an aweful waste and not very efficient.

Is it possible to harness passportjs to create a facebook session from an existing token+facebook id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token) strategy is designed to handle just this situation.